# How to update a picklist field from all existing Accounts based on another field condition? (With no Apex)

Tags: visual-workflow, account, critical-update

Hi and thanks for reading!

I have created a flow that updates the Account 'Giving Circles' picklist field based on the Account's Total Gifts.

For example:

If Account_Total_Gifts__c is between 1000 and 5000 then 'Giving Circles' == Option1

IF Account_Total_Gifts__c is between 5001 and 10000 then 'Giving Circles' == Option2
Etc

This flow will start working for newly created Accounts from now onwards, but I need to update all the Accounts that already existed in the Org based on these requirements.

There is currently about 5000 accounts in the org, but it will grow.

What would be the best option for doing this without using Apex?
Or is it better to use Apex for this scenario?

I was checking the dataloader.io but it seems I cannot add conditions for my requirements.

Comment: How many Accounts are there on the org? (This can inform as to the best approach.) Please [edit] to add the answer to this.

Comment: Updated thank you

Comment: use a scheduled-triggered flow that you run once

Comment: could work with a scheduled flow. I want to know the best practices for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data volumes, if you are looking for a non-Apex solution to this then Dataloader (or Dataloader.io) would work for this. It isn't a one step process, but the following would work:

1. Export the existing Accounts, ensuring that the Id and Account_Total_Gifts__c fields are included.
2. Add a Giving Circles header to the file that is produced, and use an Excel formula to populate the column based on the logic you have included above
3. Update the existing Accounts with the updated Giving Circles value, matching on the ID

Although this is a more manual task, it does remove the requirement for you to write Apex and I'm including as an alternative solution in addition to what Phil has provided above.

Answer (score 1):

With only 5000 accounts in the org you can easily accomplish this data setting using anonymous apex executed from the Developer Console, from the Setup UI.

You have two basic options:

1. Do a simple update to each Account that will invoke the flow or
2. Reproduce the flow's logic in Apex.

I'd go with the first option if that can be done easily - it rather depends on the flow's entry conditions (which you haven't provided).

Use anonymous apex to update the Accounts appropriately, perhaps something like the following (I've made some assumptions, listed below):

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Giving_Circles__c = NULL];
List<Account> updates = new List<Account>();

for (Account account : accounts) {
  updates.add(new Account(Id = account.Id, Some_Field__c = someValue));
}

update updates;
```

Assumptions:

- The "Giving Circles" field has an API name of `Giving_Circles__c`.
- This field is NULL for all Accounts that need to be updated.
- You can set `Some_Field__c` (insert real field name here) to `someValue` (insert real value here) to cause your flow to be initiated. Note that this value could potentially come from the Account record itself (if you add it to the query).
- Your flow is a before save record triggered flow.
- You run the above as your sys admin.

Clearly, be careful to ensure that whatever update you do here is reasonable to do and won't lose any data. The idea is to simply cause the flow to be invoked to set the `Giving_Circles__c` field value appropriately. Like I said, what you do in your anonymous apex totally depends on your entry conditions for your flow.

Anon apex is likely good enough since you can query up to 50000 records in your transaction and can update up to 10000 records in that same transaction. Again, it may fail if you have further automation that has side-effects of running queries or performing DMLs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil :)
I was looking for a non Apex solution, but this would totally work.

Comment: If it's a one-time thing that can be done via Apex, there's no reason to avoid it. Assuming you can write a bit of code, of course.

Comment: No need to copy updated records from one list to another, that just wastes CPU time for no good reason.

Comment: In this case, since I didn't query other fields that don't need updating, that is true. However, CPU time lost here is likely irrelevant in a one time process and the secondary list is a best practice for when the queried records do contain fields relevant to the processing but not relevant to the update.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a picklist field in all existing accounts based on another field condition without using Apex code can be done using a combination of Salesforce formula fields and the "Mass Update Records" feature. Here's how:

Create a new formula field on the Account object that will return the desired picklist value based on the condition of another field. For example, if you want to update the Industry field based on the Account Type field, you could create a formula field with the following formula:

IF( Account_Type__c = "Prospect", "Retail",
IF( Account_Type__c = "Customer", "Wholesale",
NULL))

Make sure the new formula field is included in the Account page layout.

Go to the Accounts tab and select all accounts you want to update by using the checkbox in the header row.

Click the "Mass Update Records" button and select "Update" from the dropdown.

In the Mass Update Records window, select the new formula field created in step 1 as the field to update, and click the "Update" button.

Verify the updates have been made successfully by checking the Industry field on individual Account records.

Note: Keep in mind that the changes made using the Mass Update Records feature are permanent and cannot be undone. It's a good practice to backup your data before making any mass updates.